# Check content of entire JSON Array in SOAP UI groovy script

Tags: json, soap, groovy, soapui

I have the following JSON response:

```
{
   "matrix":[
      {
         "abc":{
            "type":"dec"
         }
      },
      {
         "abc":{
            "type":"dec"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

how can I put assertion on entire content of "matrix" array, without converting the JSON response to XML?

Comment: What is it that you want to assert against? What are you comparing against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out the way

```
assert jsonSlurper.matrix.toString() == '["abc":{"type":"dec"}]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsed JSON in groovy is a common map. You can do some validations agains this map. 
E.g.

```
def list = [[id:'1',no:'1'],[id:'2',no:'3']]
assert list.every { it.id.isNumber() }
assert list.every { it.keySet().contains('val') }
```

Or JSON schema..

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def m = """{
    "matrix" : [
        {
           "abc" : {
               "type":"dec"
           },
        },
        {
           "abc" : {
               "type":"dec"
           }
        }
     ]
}""" 
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(m) 
assert parsed.matrix.every { it.abc.type in ['dec'] }

def ResponseMessage =  testRunner.testCase.testSteps["TestStepName"].testRequest.response.contentAsStri‌​ng 
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage) 
assert  jsonSlurper.matrix.every {it.abc.type in ['dec']}
```

Comment: could you please add a sample snippet?

Comment: def ResponseMessage = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["TestStepName"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
log.info(jsonSlurper)  prints {"matrix":["abc":{"type":"dec"}]}  how can i apply assertion on this?

Comment: Updated the answer once again.

Comment: Thanks for your help Opal. assert jsonSlurper.matrix.toString() == '["abc":{"type":"dec"}]' does the thing what i want.